# how I can print all case element in array by js

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinatorics

I have array `[1,2,3,4]`

I want to print all combinations like:

> [1]
>   [2]
>   [3]
>   [4]
>   [1,2]
>   [1,2,3]
>   [1,2,3,4]
>   [2,3]
>   [2,3,4]
>   [3,4]
>   [1,3]
>   [1,3,4]
>   [1,4]
>   [2,4]

How I can do that?

Comment: print? print where? console? screen? printer? have you tried anything or did you mistake SO for icanhazcode.com

Comment: This is actually a very annoying thing to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048621/get-all-combinations-for-a-string

Comment: umh, can use console or document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to do recursively:

```js
function printCombinations(arr, prefix) {
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    if (prefix.length > 0) {
      console.log(prefix);
    }
    return;
  }
  prefix = prefix || [];
  printCombinations(arr.slice(1), prefix.concat(arr[0]));
  printCombinations(arr.slice(1), prefix);
}

printCombinations([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```