# In Javascript, is there a function that returns the maximum list of formed integer numbers from a number pass as a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to form a maximum list of integer values from a given non-negative number pass as a string to the function below. My approach below is the formnumber() function that takes an input argument that can be rearranged into a maximum list of numbers without changing the characters within number pass as argument. My code below is generating a random set of numbers with different set of characters from what is within the argument pass to the function as a string. Expected output example: "346,634,646,463" as much n umber as possible without changing the individual number pass to the function

```
function formnumbers (input) {

    let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*input);

    return random;
}

console.log(formnumbers('436'));
```

Comment: I have no idea what the title is meant to mean.  What are "**formed** integer numbers"?

Comment: After the edits, it's still unclear what exactly you're trying to do.  What are the expected outputs of this function?

Comment: Okay, you want to generate all combinations of those characters.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048621/get-all-combinations-for-a-string), and adapt the answer to filter the result strings by length.

Comment: So you want to do permutations?

Answer (score 0):

From the list of possible solutions pointed out via the link from Amy, this code works perfect for me. You might have to use regular expression sanitize digits if an alphanumeric string is passed to the function.

```
var tree = function(leafs) {
  var branches = [];
  if (leafs.length == 1) return leafs;
  for (var k in leafs) {
    var leaf = leafs[k];
    tree(leafs.join('').replace(leaf, '').split('')).concat("").map(function(subtree) {
      branches.push([leaf].concat(subtree));
    });
  }
  return branches;
};
console.log(tree("abc".split('')).map(function(str) {
  return str.join('')
}))
```